# How can you split ggplot from 12 individual bars to 3 groups of 4?

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I have a bar graph with 12 individual bars. I would like to split them into their 3 respective groups, each with their own color so that they are recognized as the same group. I have been using ColorBrewer Set 3, because it is photocopy safe. When I use it on my plot it all turns one color.

In the plot, you can see the 3 groups - ELE, KEB, and SMI, each with 4 blocks. It would be great if they could be split up more cohesively.

```
# A tibble: 12 x 7
   vid.order sum.correct     n prop.correct z_score       p_val sig  
   <chr>           <int> <int>        <dbl>   <dbl>       <dbl> <lgl>
 1 ELE1               47    55        0.855    5.26 0.000000145 TRUE 
 2 ELE2               46    55        0.836    4.99 0.000000607 TRUE 
 3 ELE3               37    55        0.673    2.56 0.0104      TRUE 
 4 ELE4               47    55        0.855    5.26 0.000000145 TRUE 
 5 KEB1               40    55        0.727    3.37 0.000749    TRUE 
 6 KEB2               46    55        0.836    4.99 0.000000607 TRUE 
 7 KEB3               47    55        0.855    5.26 0.000000145 TRUE 
 8 KEB4               44    55        0.8      4.45 0.00000860  TRUE 
 9 SMI1               35    55        0.636    2.02 0.0431      TRUE 
10 SMI2               46    55        0.836    4.99 0.000000607 TRUE 
11 SMI3               41    55        0.745    3.64 0.000272    TRUE 
12 SMI4               35    55        0.636    2.02 0.0431      TRUE 

byBlot_sigtests %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=vid.order, y=prop.correct))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(.9))+
  labs(x="video", y="proportion natural selected")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = .5) +
  expand_limits(y=c(0,1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  jtools::theme_apa()
```

[image: Here is the plot I have]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally I would create a column with the groups (ELE, KEB or SMI) and use that in `aes(fill = )`

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(jtools)

#make object data.table
setDT(byBlot_sigtests)

#create a column with the groups (vid.order but without the numbers)
byBlot_sigtests[, group := gsub("[0-9]", "", vid.order)]

#plot
byBlot_sigtests %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=vid.order, y=prop.correct, fill = group))+
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position=position_dodge(.9))+
  labs(x="video", y="proportion natural selected")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = .5) +
  expand_limits(y=c(0,1)) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette = "Set3") +
  jtools::theme_apa()
```

[image: result]

Comment: That's perfect! I keep getting this error though: ```Error in `:=`(group, gsub("[0-9]", "", vid.order)) : 
  Check that is.data.table(DT) == TRUE. Otherwise, := and `:=`(...) are defined for use in j, once only and in particular ways. See help(":=").```

Comment: my bad. Use the line ```setDT(byBlot_sigtests)``` first to make it a data.table object. Or don't use data.table and use ```gsub``` in base R
```byBlot_sigtests$group <- gsub("[0-9]", "", byBlot_sigtests$vid.order)```
The data.table package is just my personal preference